# String Tokenizer separation

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I want to know how can we separate words of a sentence where delimiter is be a ' '(space) or '?'
or '.'. 
For ex

Input: `THIS IS A STRING PROGRAM.IS THIS EASY?YES,IT IS`.

Output:

```
THIS
IS
A
STRING
PROGRAM
IS
THIS
EASY
YES
IT
IS
```

Comment: have you tried the stringTokenizer.nextElement method ?

Comment: refer to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the constructor of the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class in Java. It has provision to accept custom delimiter.

Try this:

```
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("THIS IS A STRING PROGRAM.IS THIS EASY?YES,IT IS", " .?");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "THIS IS A STRING PROGRAM.IS THIS EASY?YES,IT IS";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

    System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
}
```